# Change switch values from '0' / '1' to strings on a Rails simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

So I'm using Rails simple_form and this input below in order to use switches:

```
class SwitchInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    input_html_classes.unshift('fg-line')
    template.content_tag(:div, class: 'toggle-switch') do
      template.concat @builder.check_box(attribute_name, input_html_options)
      template.concat inline_label
    end
  end

  def inline_label
    template.content_tag(:label, class: 'ts-helper') do
      template.concat options[:inline_label]
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to create a switch that saves the input value as a string; if it's switched to the left (default), then the value being saved is "small" and if the switch is turned to the right, then the value being saved is "large".

Right now I am saving the value as "small" / "large" via a `before_save` callback:

```
  private def convert_switch_value
    if size == '0'
      self.size = 'small'
    else
      self.size = 'large'
    end

    return true
  end
```

This is problematic because when the user returns to the form, the value being saved isn't being shown with the switch; the switch is always turned off regardless of the value being saved into the database.

Is there a way to just use simple_form to save the string values into the database AND showing the stored value when re-entering the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with simple_form, but it is probably not simple_form's concern to change form values before save.

My guess is that there are instances where calling `model.size` you would actually expect it to return `'small'` or `'large'`, and not `'0'` or `'1'`. If so, just overriding getters and setters in the model won't work.

Try [reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) gem. It's helpful when you have multiple "ways"  of setting model values. Reform is a middleman between form renderer and model. You would attach your model to reform object and pass reform object to simple_form instead of passing the model to it. Inside reform's form object you can put all form-parsing logic. Here is an example:

```
class YourModelForm < Reform::Form
  property :size

  def size # override getter
    if super == 'small'
      '0'
    elsif super == 'large'
      '1'  
    end
  end

  def size=(value) # override setter
    if value == '0'
      super('small')
    elsif value == '1'
      super('large')
    end
  end
end
```